# How to make an apply button in powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, button

I'm making a GUI and I need a button, that doesn't close the window on click.

Just copying from some of my other code for button creation, which works fine, but closes the window, on click. I need something that doesn't close the window, when clicked.

```
$apply = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$apply.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 120)
$apply.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50, 22)
$apply.Text = "Apply"
# $apply.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::
```

I'm making a GUI and I need a button, that doesn't close the window on click, like an apply button, does.

Answer (score 0):

A button in a GUI with text <kbd>Apply</kbd> usually means some setting is performed without closing the window.
You just need to add an Click event handler to the button like:

```
$apply.Add_Click(
    {    
       # here you do whatever the Apply is meant for
    }
)
```

Another button called <kbd>OK</kbd> is usually also present which also applies whatever is was, but does close the form.